# Проблемы с драйвером MS Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado

Приложение на Delphi 2007, ADO, MS Access, нормально работает на Windows XP, 7, c Office 2007/2010 (забыл какой именно).
На Windows 10 64-bit с 16-м офисом, для работы нужно устанавливать Microsoft Access database engine 2010 32-bit.
Есть ли способы сделать так, чтобы приложение работало без установки дополнительного ПО?

Comment: а как вы хотите получить доступ к БД без драйвера этой БД? никак. кроме того вам еще и разрядность потребуется одинаковая (с офисом). С 2007м офисом мб еще и работало без драйвера (если там была еще `mdb`-база), и то вряд ли, но с 2010м точно не работало.

Comment: возможно нормально оно работало на старой системе, т.к. драйвер уже ставили когда то ранее и забыли про это.